# Is there a way to make ActiveRecord compatible class for custom SQL queries (preloader/includes)?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm currently trying to find a clean way of using some custom SQL Queries together with ActiveRecord. The main reason is to use preloader/include system of active record.

Super over-simplified example of how it could ideally work:

```
class ArticleViewsByUser

  query <<-SQL
    SELECT user_id, SUM(articles.view_count) as view_count
    FROM articles
    GROUPED BY articles.user_id 
  SQL

  class Row
    belongs_to :user
    attr_reader :view_count
  end

end

class ArticleViewsByCategory

  query <<-SQL
    SELECT category_id, SUM(articles.view_count) as view_count
    FROM articles
    GROUPED BY articles.category_id 
  SQL

  class Row
    belongs_to :category
    attr_reader :view_count
  end

end

ArticleViewsByUser.new.includes(:user)
...

ArticleViewsByUser.new.includes(:category)
...
```

I'm aware it could be done with just both the `User` and `Article` models in this case, but only by adding code (fake fields via attr_reader) that is not relevant to either those. Doing that same with 10+ fields to sum/calculate also goes out of hand fast.

Adding DB views would be one way for sure, but also brings a lot of overhead to manage those in DB.

So far i could not find anything in this direction, which kinda surprised me.
Has there been anything like this? Maybe a gem?

Comment: Would definitely go views -- can create ActiveRecord models based on them. Maintaining them in the database is not difficult. Can create migrations, or simply add the definition files to the project and enhance the migration task to always run the definition file.

Comment: You can certainly accomplish this goal (or something close to it) using the similar or differing semantics and constructing the queries with `Arel` but if you want objects that are truly AR objects then views is your way to go. Otherwise you are looking at a significant amount of meta programming, which *could/should* work but would be far less graceful.

Comment: @engineersmnky ActiveRecord actually does most of the crazy metaprogramming for you. When you do a select it will automatically add getters for all the resulting rows. For example if you do `Arcticle.joins(:views).select("*", "COUNT(views.*) AS view_count").group(:id)` the resulting model instances will already have a `view_count` method.

Comment: I do agree that using a view is a better idea then having something that looks like a model but actually represents results from different tables. AR is built around the basic principle that a model corresponds to a single table and when you break that assumption a lot of kittens die.

Comment: You can achieve by including Active model into the class `include ActiveModel::Model`

Comment: @max I was referring to top down metaprogramming (as I think we are going to have to patch AR to support this either directly or indirectly) also AR does not add getters at all. AR collates the columns into a hash and AM then just checks this Hash using method_missing. My point was if the OP wants "models" that correspond to a "table" that happens to be an arbitrary query we are gonna have to crack a few eggs. The OP seems to care more about the ability to leverage eager/preloading/joins conditionally at will which is a bit more complicated than just providing dynamic accessors to a Hash.

Comment: I have jumped into Views now. The Activerecord part is pretty neat, using regular models including preloader, joins, and sorting logic. However managing the views is really quite a pain with all that hardcoded SQL files. Lots of copy&past, editing and re-running migrations – in code SQL would have been easier to generate/template. But i guess once it runs it's worth the extra effort. THX everyone

Comment: The suggestion of @max was also one alternative i was thinking about or actually where i started from. Just wrapping the "main" source table model into a new class. But that quickly turns into quite a hack, when only using a few of the original fields and adding a dozen more via custom `select` and calculations. But it would be a native AR query with all the bonuses (includes, joins, etc) working.

Comment: I think you're greatly exaggerating the downsides of using a view. The scenic gem can be used to create and update views with a relative ease. Also materialized views behave just like a table so you can use the whole ActiveRecord query interface and assocations and it just works. The alternative here is a lot more iffy.

Comment: @max unfortunately i'm on mysql, so no materialized views for me. I'm using the scenic gem for managing the views. the release process is flawless and no overhead. in development it is quite cumbersome to continuously update the views, compared to editing a query in active record. no edit and refresh, having to re-run migrations in between each edit. But as it's mostly for relatively static models, the views still seem to be the better choice overall.